# Date value wrongly formatted

Tags: java, parsing, simpledateformat

I am trying to convert a String `DateTime` value which is present in a flat file as a `Date` object after parsing the flat file in my code.

I have written the code to do that but when I format the date its always giving me a date more than 1 day for the specified value, some times it's adding 5:30.

Below is the code for that:

```
    DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zz yyyy");
    Date date = f.parse("Tue Aug 23 20:00:03 PDT 2011");
    System.out.println("---date----" + date);
```

The output for the above is

```
    ---date----Wed Aug 24 08:30:03 IST 2011
```

Can you please let me know whats the issue here. Is there a problem in the pattern that I am using in the `SimplaDateFormat` class or is there a problem with the code.
I have been scratching my head on this for a long time now.

Comment: Have you tried to set a time zone to your DateFormat object? What timezone it has?

Comment: Didn't you satisfied with the answers here? Please accept answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your system timezone is different.  The output is showing IST - or Indian Standard Time, which is an 12.5h difference from PDT.  The code is properly parsing the given date which is PDT (UTC -7) and printing out IST (UTC +5h30).

Java stores Dates as UTC dates.  So when you parse the PDT date, Java will convert it to UTC and store it internally as a UTC timestamp.  When you print, if you do not specify the timezone, it will default to the system timezone, which in your case would appear to be IST.

To specify an exact timezone, specify it in the SimpleDateFormat:

```
DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zz yyyy");
f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PDT"));
Date date = f.parse("Tue Aug 23 20:00:03 PDT 2011");
System.out.println("---date----" + f.format(date));
```

Comment: Hi Eric.Thanks.I have made the changes that you have shown above but its not working its still showing the same time difference as my original question.

Comment: Sorry... cut & paste typo.  I made a small edit to the code snippet.

Answer (score 6):

> Can you please let me know whats the issue here.

Sure. You're effectively calling `date.toString()`, which doesn't know *anything* about the `SimpleDateFormat` which was used to parse the original text value. A `Date` is *just* an instant in time. It has no notion of a per-instance format. Additionally, it doesn't know about a time zone. You've given a value in PDT, which was then parsed... and when you *print* it, it's using the system local time zone (IST). That's what `Date.toString` *always* does.

If you want to format a `Date` in a particular way, using a particular format in a particular time zone, call `DateFormat.format`.

Comment: Thanks Jon.i have rectified the error that i made. i have a new date format DateFormat f2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"); and i want to do something like this Date dateParsed = f2.parse(originalDate); to get the old date into a new format. i am getting a java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue Aug 23 20:00:03 PDT 2011" . is it possible to do this way

Comment: @vikeng21: Well your new format doesn't mention the time zone - it doesn't conform to the text value you've got, so yes, it will fail to parse that way. You should use your *existing* format to parse, and then the *new* format to format. You should think about setting the time zone explicitly though.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not formatting a `date`. Look at the example

```
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Locale currentLocale = Locale.US;
    DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zz yyyy", currentLocale);
    Date date = null;
    Date today;
    try {
      today = new Date();
      String result = f.format(today);
      System.out.println("Locale: " + currentLocale.toString());
      System.out.println("Result: " + result);
      date = f.parse("Tue Aug 23 20:00:03 PDT 2011");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();  
    }
    System.out.println("---date----" + f.format(date));
  }
```

will output

```
Locale: en_US
Result: Tue Sep 25 19:12:38 EEST 2012
---date----Tue Aug 23 20:00:03 PDT 2011
```

Now, you have a bit modified code

```
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Locale currentLocale = Locale.US;
    DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zz yyyy", currentLocale);
    DateFormat f2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zz yyyy", currentLocale);
    Date date = null;
    Date today;
    try {
      today = new Date();
      String result = f.format(today);
      System.out.println("Locale: " + currentLocale.toString());
      System.out.println("Result: " + result);
      date = f.parse("Tue Aug 23 20:00:03 PDT 2011");
      System.out.println("---date----" + f.format(date));
      System.out.println("---date----" + f2.format(date));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

which outputs to

```
Locale: en_US
Result: Tue Sep 25 20:42:10 EEST 2012
---date----Tue Aug 23 20:00:03 PDT 2011
---date----Wed Aug 24 06:00:03 EEST 2011
```

seems that `SimpleDateFormat` don't care about timezone even if `'z'` pattern is specified. It is setting the timezone when it parses the input. That's how I can describe that a strange behavior. Then use of `'z'` pattern seems obsolete and lead to unpredictable results.

so setting the `TimeZone` will fix the issue

```
f2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
```

Comment: Hi Roman. Thanks i got what mistake i was doing. Just a follow up i have a new date format DateFormat f2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"); and i want to do something like this Date dateParsed = f2.parse(originalDate); to get the old date into a new format. i am getting a java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue Aug 23 20:00:03 PDT 2011" can you let me know how i can solve this error.

Comment: @vikeng21 In the new format parsable date will look like "2011-08-23 20:00:03.000"

Comment: In the new format however you didn't specify 'z' for timezone and in my zone it will "2011-08-24 06:00:03.000"

Comment: Did you get the answers here? Please accept the answer.